# Jest test init conditions

Tags: jestjs

Lets say I have a file `file1.js` which contains:

```
const a = true;
let b;

if (a) {
    b = c;
}

if (!a) {
    b = d;
}
```

Now when I run test case on this file my first condition gets covered. Is there any way that I can cover second condition by setting `a` to false or should I change my code in a way that I can call a method with different values to test for each case kind of like:

```
const a = true;

getBVal(a) {
  return a ? c : d;
}

let b = getBVal(a);
```

> Update:

Below is my code for requestAnimationFrame with fallbacks for older browsers:

```
let lastTime = 0;
const vendors = ["ms", "moz", "webkit", "o"];
let rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame;

if (!rAF) {
  rAF = vendors.find(prefix => window[`${prefix}RequestAnimationFrame`]);
}

if (!rAF) {
  rAF = cB => {
    const currTime = new Date().getTime();
    const timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      cB(currTime + timeToCall);
    }, timeToCall);
    lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
    return id;
  };
}

function requestAnimationFrame(callback) {
  return rAF(callback);
}

export default requestAnimationFrame;
```

I am using jsdom in setup for window object. Now if I have to test case for `window.requestAnimationFrame = null` its not possible in the way I have written my code

Now after changing it to:

```
import { requestAnimationFrameVendor } from "../constants";

let lastTime = 0;

const customFn = cB => {
  const currTime = new Date().getTime();
  const timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
  const id = setTimeout(() => {
    cB(currTime + timeToCall);
  }, timeToCall);
  lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
  return id;
};

function requestAnimationFrame(callback) {
  const rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame;
  return rAF && rAF(callback) || requestAnimationFrameVendor && requestAnimationFrameVendor(callback) || customFn(callback);
}

export default requestAnimationFrame;
```

And then if I write test like:

```
import * as constants from "../../constants";

describe("animationFrame", () => {
  let requestAnimationFrame;
  let cancelAnimationFrame;

  beforeAll(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame = global.window.requestAnimationFrame;
    cancelAnimationFrame = global.window.cancelAnimationFrame;
  });

  test("requestAnimationFrame", done => {
    global.window.requestAnimationFrame = null;
    global.window.cancelAnimationFrame = null;

    const requestId1 = Utils.requestAnimationFrame(jest.fn());

    constants.requestAnimationFrameVendor = jest.fn(() => {
      return requestAnimationFrame;
    });

    const requestId2 = Utils.requestAnimationFrame(jest.fn());

    setTimeout(() => {
      Utils.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId1);
      Utils.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId2);
      done();
    }, 300);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    global.window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame = null;
    global.window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame = null;
  });
});
```

Then it covers all the conditions.

Comment: How can this even be called in production code?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle just an example. Just wanted to know if there's anyway we could change constant values within a file for covering test cases.

Comment: That's my point, when you can't do it in production you can/should not do it in tests.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I have added an update. Please go through it. If any better suggestions or any mistakes in test please add a reply. Will help a lot. Note: I know I need to write expect func to be called but for now just wrote the test to see coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the second rout (`getBVal()`) because it makes your interface more testable.

In general, removing global state (like your `const a` or `let b`) will make your code and interfaces more testable. If you cannot remove the global state completely, you can introduce abstractions so that your test does not need to know about the global state (like your suggested `getBVal()`).

Maybe you can go even further and remove the global `b`: Instead always call `getBVal()` instead? The performance impact will be negligible in most cases, and your code becomes even more testable and less coupled...

Comment: So with jest there is no way I can change value of constant in a file?

Comment: I don't know of any. And even if there was one, I would not use it, because this would couple the test too closely to the implementation of the file AND I think having that additional API is a good idea in many cases anyway.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Will wait for any other responses for a week. If no better answer comes then will accept yours. Thanks